# ".hasClass" with if statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<nav id="navbar-main" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top main-nav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="#head-logo" src="images/logo.png"></a>
</div>
```

The above navbar changes when scrolled from top and a class is added - "affix" , I want to change the source of the image inside navbar-brand when the navbar have the class "affix". 
But the following doesn't work -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       if ($("#navbar-main").hasClass('affix')) {
          $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src','second.jpg');
    }
    else {
       $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src','images/logo.png');
    }
});
```

The following Works -

```
   $(window).scroll(function (){
       var navscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
       if(navscroll >= 50) {
          $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src','second.jpg');
    }
    else {
       $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src','images/logo.png');
    }
});
```

Comment: When are you calling `logochange`?

Comment: If it works then it is good...what you want to do

Comment: @Ashishsah Do not encourage hosting code on a third-party site. People should use the Code Snippets functionality built-in to the questions.

Comment: but what about complex codes?? I don't think doing so is a bad idea

Comment: This can, of course, be done with CSS by showing/hiding the appropriate `img` based on its parent having `.affix`...

Comment: @Ashishsah: The full content of the question must be **in** the question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help. The problem with suggesting off-site locations is people leave important code out of the question. A [mcve] can be done in a snippet in nearly all cases (forms and web storage being exceptions); where not possible, the full code should be in the question with an **optional** link to an example on a big site like jsFiddle. Normally that's not necessary, snippets are enough.

Comment: @mike, please check now, i want to usse it in .ready function

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , Yes it can be done using CSS, but I want to do it using script only

Comment: The callback for ready is only evaluated once when the DOM was fully build, so the test  hasClass test is only done once, and not when the class was changed.

Comment: you need to add a event listener that will call that code on certain event like scroll

Comment: you have to use your 2nd method inside that you can use 1 methods code

Comment: @t.niese, yes I got it now, don't know JSs much, so used ready function, is there any solution to this without the scroll function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class is being added/removed on scroll, you'll need to put your code in a `scroll` callback and run it **after** the class has been added/removed (if you base the change on the class). `ready` is only run once, when the page is loaded and parsed.

So for instance, you might do this:

```
function updateLogo() {
    if ($("#navbar-main").hasClass('affix')) {
          $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src','second.jpg');
    }
    else {
       $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src','images/logo.png');
    }
}
$(updateLogo);
$(window).on("scroll", updateLogo);
```

...but only if you know that the code doing the class update has already registered its `scroll` handler (because handlers are executed in order, so if it's already registered its before your code above is run, yours is registered after). If you don't know that, you'll need to do something to ensure you call `updateLogo` after the class update.

---

From your comment:

> I don't want to make it work using scroll, but when the class changes...

There's no "on class change" event. You have to identify what it is that causes the class change, and then trigger off whatever that is. Or poll (blech). :-)

Or do the rational thing and use CSS rather than making more work for yourself. :-)

```
img.affixed {
    display: none;
}
.affix img.normal {
    display: none;
}
.affix img.affixed {
    display: inline;
}
```

...where `img class="normal"` is the `images/logo.png` image, and `img class="affixed"` is the `second.jpg` image.

Comment: I think he is doing that

Comment: Got it, I don't know Java script much, can you help me with the right code if you understood what I want to do ?

Comment: @Ashishsah , yes you are right brother, I don't want to make it work using scroll, but when the class changess

Comment: @AdarshGurjar that can only be done by listening any event and here the scroll event is the easiest way...I think you should use that

Comment: @AdarshGurjar: There's no "on class change" event. You have to identify what it is that causes the class change, and then trigger off whatever that is. Or do the rational thing and use CSS rather than making more work for yourself. :-)